# Can you set starttag and endtag to queryselector JS

Tags: javascript, dom

Can you set start tag and end tag to a queryselector. I mean can I start to search from the first div with class button to the next class button. I mean I only want to select ONLY the FIRST div with class content, that is between 2 divs with class button

```
<body>
    <div class = 'content'> test </div>
    <div class = 'button'>lqlqlq</div>
    <div class = 'content'> test </div>
    <div class = 'content'> test </div>
    <div class = 'button'>lqlqlq</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do that with just a query selector. You'll have to loop through. The `prev` and `next` functions will be your friend. Something like this:

```
var foundDiv = null;
$("div").each( function() {
  var prev = $(this).prev();
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (prev && next && $(prev).hasClass('button') && $(next).hasClass('button') && $(this).hasClass('content')) {
    foundDiv = this;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't wrong, but note that the OP did not include jQuery in the list of tags, and did explicity ask about `.querySelector()`.

Comment: Yes I do realize that. I'm "encouraging" him to use jQuery. Something like this would be messy without it.